# How come this print function for linked list works?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
  char val;
  Node* tail;
};
```

I initiate a linked list like so:

```
Node* header;
Node node_one;
node_one.val = 'a';
node_one.tail = 0;
header = &node_one;
```

And then I keep adding nodes to this list. Now when I use the below print function for this linked list, it works the way it is expected to work:

```
void printlist(Node* header) {
    do{
        printf("%c ", header->val);
        header = header->tail; // aren't we modifying the header itself here?
    } while(header->tail!=0);

    printf("%c --> NULL", header->val);
}
```

Called from `main()` as `printlist(header);`

So far so good. What I don't get is, without making any changes to the list, when I call this print function the second, third, fourth time, it always works. It prints the elements of the list. But what I was expecting was that this function would only work once because I am modifying the header pointer itself so shouldn't I lose the list in the memory after running this print function once? How come it works more than once?

Comment: Have a look at Binky Pointer Fun Video C++: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i49_SNt4yfk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `header` you use in the `printlist()` body is not the same `header` than the one you refer to in `main()`.  These are to different variables that just happen to have the same name.

*You can experiment with this principle by chaning the name of `header` in `printlist()`: call it for example `mylist`, and the whole programme will still work.*

Comment: Yes, `header` is not a global variable and the pointer I declare in `main()` has the name `header`. So is it like this? When I call `printlist(header);` it makes a copy of `header` which is a pointer, and making a copy of that pointer will mean that the copy is pointing to the same location as `header` itself. So in `printlist()` what I am modifying is not `header` itself but its copy? That's how I am able to run that function over and over?

Comment: Yes exactly !  You got it !

Comment: I totally skipped the fact that even if it's a pointer I'm passing to a function, unless I'm passing the address of it, I am just passing a copy. Thank you and Shantanu for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the header in the function below is a local variable(local to the function printlist). So your original header (header in the main) is not changing at all. So, whenever you call this function it is still printing the list.

```
void printlist(Node* header){
    do{
        printf("%c ", header->val);
        header = header->tail; // aren't we modifying the header itself here?
    }while(header->tail!=0);
    printf("%c --> NULL", header->val);
 }
```